# Kubedb operator issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, kubernetes

Has anyone used the kubedb operator before? https://kubedb.com/docs/0.9.0/welcome/

I've gotten a postgres instance bootstrapped and now im trying to do a snapshot to s3 but cant seem to get it working

`Waiting... database is not ready yet`

The db is up and accepting connections:

```
$ kubectl exec -it db-0 -n ${namespace} bash
  bash-4.3# pg_isready
  /var/run/postgresql:5432 - accepting connections
```

The db pod is running at :

`db-0                       1/1       Running   0          37m`

Which is accessible in pgadmin via the server name `db.${namespace}`

Here's my snapshot object spec:

```
---
apiVersion: kubedb.com/v1alpha1
kind: Snapshot
metadata:
  name: db-snapshot
  namespace: ${namespace}
  labels:
    kubedb.com/kind: Postgres
spec:
  databaseName: db
  storageSecretName: s3-creds
  s3:
    endpoint: 's3.amazonaws.com'
    bucket: ${bucket}
```

If anyone can point out where im going wrong that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

```
#while ! nc "$DB_HOST" "$DB_PORT" -w 30 >/dev/null; do
#  echo "Waiting... database is not ready yet"
#  sleep 5
#done
```

This nc command wasnt connecting to the db host for some reason.
The container could psql into it using the db name so I commented it out and it worked like a charm.

Guess there's some issue with the nc binary that's bundled in this container.

Comment: It is working fine in kubedb tests. Need to take a look in `nc` shortcoming. Glad you found a workaround. :)

Comment: Thanks! In the meantime Ill open an issue on the github,

Comment: The reason is that your db service is named `db`, so the `$DB_PORT` env var is injected into the container with a value like `tcp://1.2.3.4:5432`.

There is no issue with `nc`.